# application not responding using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, asynchronous, processbuilder

I'm currently doing an Eclipse plugin mainly calling various scripts and interact with the return values.

my main problem is the ProcessBuilder. If I e.g. call a script that's creating a new Visual Basic window I'm not able to interact with the plugin anymore till I close the VB window. Seems that the cmd command is still running in the background and only after it stops the plugin responds again.

how am I able to fix it? should it run asynchronous in any way?

this is the ProcessBuilder I'm using:

```
public void execute(String scriptCMD) {
  try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c",
        scriptCMD);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
      line = r.readLine();
      if (line == null) {break;}
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example of execution of the process asynchronously in another thread. I've used the single thread executor because there's only one task executed:

```
java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c",
        scriptCMD);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
      line = r.readLine();
      if (line == null) {break;}
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks 2 things: newSingleThreadedExecutor() seems undefined for Executors, using java.util.concurrent.Executors and scriptCMD needs to be set to final should be ok or?

Comment: forget the last comment, eclipse restart fixed the problem. thanks for the fast and reliable answer ! works like a charm

Comment: Yes, the argument of the method should be set final, nothing bad about it.